# Create layered navigation filter for rating

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

How we can Create layered navigation filter for rating .
please see attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Directly it's difficult to achieve, but you can achieve this by this logic.

Create an attribute for that and change the attribute value with the observer `review_save_after`. In this event, you get the product and review summary, and update your attribute value from this. Add that attribute to layered navigation.

Comment: So Attribute will be "Multiple Select" ? Right?

Comment: Yes , You can .you can create multiselect or select on your requirement bases.

Comment: How can I save previously rated product data?

Comment: you can create a stand alone script where you get saved rating and save those rating in that attribute

Comment: @MohitKumarArora please check my above comment